# Function to escape characters in paths

Tags: powershell, path, escaping, powershell-3.0, microsoft-bits

Is there a function in PowerShell for escaping characters in paths?

NB: I'm aware that most cmdlets which provide a `Path` parameter also provide a `LiteralPath` parameter which resolves this issue.  This question is more from curiosity than need, as in most use cases I can think of, switching to `LiteralPath` makes sense.  However there are some genuine use-cases (e.g. `Start-BitsTransfer` has a `Source` parameter, but no literal equivalent).

#### Detail

If I have a file `c:\temp\test[0123].txt`, instead of `Get-Item 'c:\temp\test[0123].txt'`, I'd have to use `` Get-Item 'c:\temp\test`[0123`].txt' `` to get a result (or make use of the `LiteralPath` parameter).

Even the path returned by another PowerShell command returns an unescaped string; i.e. `Get-ChildItem 'c:\temp\' -Filter 'test*.txt' | Convert-Path | Get-Item` fails (NB: if we pass the actual `FileSystemInfo` object all works, but that object has no properties with the correctly escaped string path).

We can easily escape this using code such as below:

```powershell
$path = 'c:\temp\test[0123].txt'
$path = $path -replace '([][[])', '`$1' # escape square brackets by adding back ticks
Get-Item $path
```

However when escaping strings, standard advice is to avoid rolling your own solution / to make use of the language's solutions to these issues.

Is there any pre-existing function in PowerShell for this purpose, or any recommended way of approaching this; or is the only option to use a bespoke function (e.g. below)?

```
function ConvertFrom-LiteralPath {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$LiteralPath
    )
    process {
        (New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property @{
            LiteralPath = $LiteralPath
            Path = $LiteralPath -replace '([][[\*\?])', '`$1' # escapes ], [, *, and ?
        })
    }
}
```

Info on special characters:

- Wildcard Queries: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692793.aspx
- File Paths: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is the following method you can use:

```
[Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape('test[1].txt')
```

Returns:

```
test`[1`].txt
```

Documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern.escape