# Ignore wildcard characters [] in Powershell strings

Tags: powershell

I've got a Powershell script that takes a filename as input.

```
param([string]$folder, [string]$input_filename)
$logfile=$folder + "\duplicate.log"
Write-Output "`nScript: `n$transformation_filename`nLogfile: " | Out-file $logfile -Append
```

This works fine for most filenames, but it breaks down when the filename or folder name contains [].

```
dupfile.ps1 "C:\foldername [w]" "filename.xml"
```

Line 3 throws this error:
Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path C:foldername [w]\duplicate.log did not resolve to a file.

So the variables have to be treated more literally.

```
$logfile='$folder' + "\duplicate.log"
```

Nope, that's too literal.

```
$logfile="$folder" + "\duplicate.log"
```

Nope, same error.

How can I tell Powershell to insert the variable value but don't try to interpret anything in that value as wildcards?

Edit: I'm using Powershell 5.
My dupfile.ps1 contains only the 3 lines above.
Using this from the PS shell to run the script:
C:_SCRIPTS_\dupfile.ps1 "C:\foldername [w]" "test.txt"

One more addition, if I may. I have a few lines that redirect their error messages to the logfile.

```
Copy-Item -LiteralPath  $inputPath -Destination $outputPath 2>&1|%{ "$_" } >>$logfile
```

The redirection trips over the [] again. I don't think I can use -LiteralPath here.

Comment: Which *PowerShell* command actually causes the error? You can probably use the `-LiteralPath` parameter there (as apposed to the default `-Path` parameter).

Comment: None of the above lines will throw that error, except maybe `dupfile.ps1 ...`. But unfortunateley we cannot look into that file. Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: I've added the requested info.

Comment: As @iRon already suggested: `Out-File -LiteralPath $logfile ...`

Comment: the -LiteralPath works for most of what I need, except when I redirect error messages. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to escape characters in paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46037095/11942268)

Comment: @stackprotector, trying `[WildcardPattern]::Escape()` is tempting and arguably _should_ work, but doesn't: the _escaped_ form of the path is used _literally_ when the file is created.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

To ensure that file-path argument `$var` in redirection operations 
`> $var` / `>> $var` is treated *literally* if it contains `[` and `]`, use

`| Out-File -LiteralPath $var` / `| Out-File -LiteralPath $var -Append` instead.

```bash
Copy-Item -LiteralPath $inputPath -Destination $outputPath 2>&1 |
  ForEach-Object { "$_" } |
  Out-File -LiteralPath $logfile # literal alternative to >> $logfile
```

As in your case, you may have to *combine* it with a [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) in order to ensure that *additional* streams beside the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) are targeted:

```bash
# Literal equivalent of *>> $logfile
... *>&1 | Out-File -LiteralPath $logfile -Append
```

Unfortunately, it gets tricky with capturing a given *other* stream *only*, as you then need to use the appropriate `-*Variable` common parameter, such as the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-errorvariable):

```bash
# Literal equivalent of 2>> $logfile
... -ErrorVariable errs
$errs | Out-File -LiteralPath $logfile -Append
```

**Caveat:**

- It is tempting to try to bypass the above solutions by *escaping* the literal path so that when it is interpreted as a *wildcard*, it is treated literally, using [`[WildcardPattern]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern.Escape).
- However, this does *not* work as expected as of PowerShell 7.2.6, because the escaped form of the literal path is then used as the *literal* file path - see [GitHub issue #9475](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9475) and also the discussion about whether `>` / `>>`, ... should treat their arguments as wildcards to begin with.

```bash
# !! Arguably SHOULD work, but doesn't as of 7.2.6:
# The file that is created is LITERALLY named for the ESCAPED form:
#  `[1`].txt
'hi' > ([WildcardPattern]::Escape('[1].txt'))
```

---

##### Background information:

The **`-Path` (`-FilePath`) parameter** of PowerShell's [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) cmdlets expects [*wildcard* expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) for targeting file-system items by a name or path *pattern*. This parameter is *implicitly* targeted by the first *positional* argument, i.e. if you don't explicitly name the target parameter - e.g., `Get-ChildItem foo` is implicitly the same as `Get-ChildItem -Path foo`.

- Surprisingly, this doesn't just apply to file-*reading* cmdlets  (e.g., `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Content`), but also to file-*writing* cmdlets (e.g., `Set-Content`, `Out-File`).

  - Note that the parameter named `-Path` is called `-FilePath` in `Out-File` for historical reasons. In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, `-Path` was introduced as an *alias name*, for consistency.
- Arguably, in file-*writing*/*creating* cmdlets this behavior is *inappropriate* - given that you usually know exactly what *literal* path you want to target - and there are several GitHub issues discussing this; an overview of all relevant discussions can be found in  [this comment on GitHub issue #17106](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17106#issuecomment-1088755835).

In order **for such arguments to be treated *literally*** (verbatim), you must

**use the `-LiteralPath` parameter** instead.

In effect, `> $var` and `>> $var` are aliases for `| Out-File -FilePath $var` and `| Out-File -FilePath $var -Append`, which implies that `$var` is interpreted *as a wildcard*.

Using explicit `Out-File` calls with `-LiteralPath`, as shown at the top, avoids this problem.